# Yocto+Pulseaudio：Unable to contact D-Bus....Connection refused

Tags: yocto, dbus, pulseaudio

I used Yocto to add pulseaudio-server to the image, but when running pulseaudio, I got this two errors:
[image: error message]

When running for the first time, the error that pulseaudio does not specify dbus appears, and the above problem occurs after adding DUBS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS to the environment variable
DUBS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS obtained by the command

```
dbus-daemon --session --print-address
```